# django application on heroku gives 'Programming error at /admin/login "auth_user" does not exist.' on login

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

After successfully deploying a Django application to Heroku I get this error when I attempt to log in via the built-in django-admin:

```
Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: relation "auth_user" does not exist
```

My application is pretty simple with just two apps. None of the apps has any views, just models and it works okay locally. The database is SQLite and migrations seem to be fine.

The error traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://******.herokuapp.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Django Version: 2.1.1
Python Version: 3.6.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'general',
 'user_details']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in login
  398.         return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in dispatch
  61.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  141.         if form.is_valid():

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  185.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  180.             self.full_clean()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  382.         self._clean_form()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  409.             cleaned_data = self.clean()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in clean
  195.             self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  73.             user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py" in authenticate
  16.             user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py" in get_by_natural_key
  44.         return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  393.         num = len(clone)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  250.         self._fetch_all()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1186.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1065.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
                                                         ^
```

One redditer suggested that maybe one of the built-in models is missing but that doesn't seem to be the case.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The database is SQLite

That's your problem.

[Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem): any changes you make to the filesystem will be lost when the dyno restarts, which [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting) (at least once per day). Since SQLite is a file-based database your data will be lost.

Heroku supports [many client-server databases](https://elements.heroku.com/addons), including [its PostgreSQL service](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) which should be configured by default. You can use something like [`dj-database-url`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url) to connect to your default database via the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

Once that's done you'll have to [run your migrations on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#types-of-one-off-dynos), e.g. via

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

You might want to set this up as a [release command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase), though I recommend that you only do that if you have good test coverage.